# Unit test is not passing because of LocaDateTime field

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, mockito

Unit test is not passing by saving because of mismatch of LocalDateTime field in UserEventHistory class.

what solutions are there to solve this issue ?

```
data class UserEventHistory(
   val id: Int = 0,
   val login: String,
   val eventType: String,
   val dateCreated: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
)

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
class UserEventServiceTest(
    @Mock
    private val repository: UserEventRepository) {

    private val service = UserEventServiceImpl(repository)

    companion object {
        private const val LOGIN = "ruabc7"
        private val EVENT_TYPE = EventType.USER_LOGIN
    }

     @Test
     fun save() {
         val userEventHistory = UserEventHistory(
         login = UserEventHistoryServiceTest.LOGIN,
         eventType = UserEventHistoryServiceTest.EVENT_TYPE.toString(),
      )

         service.save(UserEventHistoryServiceTest.LOGIN, 
            UserEventHistoryServiceTest.EVENT_TYPE)

         verify(repository)
             .save(same(userEventHistory))
     }
}
```

The error message is following:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
repository.save(
UserEventHistory(id=0, login=ruabc7, eventType=USER_LOGIN, dateCreated=2021- 
02-15T12:42:54.348218)
);
-> at ru.raiffeisen.bgt.auth.service.impl.UserEventHistoryServiceTest.save
(UserEventHis 
toryServiceTest.kt:37)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
repository.save(
UserEventHistory(id=0, login=ruabc7, eventType=USER_LOGIN, dateCreated=2021- 
02-15T12:42:54.350623)
);
```

The repository is following:

```
@Repository
public interface UserEventRepository : CrudRepository<UserEventHistory, Int> 
{}
```

Comment: What does "mismatch of LocalDateTime field in UserEventHistory" mean? What is the exact and complete errormessage you get? How does the implementation of the service look like? Why is this tagged spring-data-jpa when everything related to it is mocked?

Comment: @JensSchauder has been edited. If you will need some more information, please let me know

Comment: You haven't posted the service yet.

Comment: Side note not relevant to the problem at hand: you don't need a `@Repository` annotation on Spring Data repositories, it is automatically implied.

Comment: Another side note not relevant to the problem at hand: `LocalDateTime` does not define a point in time and therefore is not suitable for use as a time stamp as you seem to do here. See http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2018/03/14/dont-use-localdatetime/

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your service uses the repository to save an `UserEventHistory` instance created inside the service.

Since this happens at a different time than the construction of `userEventHistory` which you use for comparison the two differ.

To fix this the test you have various options:

Change the implementation of `equals` in the `UserEventHistory`, so it doesn't take the date into account. This sounds wrong to me but certainly is technically possible, although I don't know how to exactly do that with Kotlin.

Use a [custom matcher](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argument-matchers) instead of `same` for comparing the `UserEventHistory` instances which ignores the `dateCreated` or makes only a rough comparison with a tolerance of maybe 0.1seconds.